# how to put figures side by side (float)

Tags: css, html, figure

```html
<figure class="left">
<img class="top" src="top10.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
<figcaption> Fig1. Production value and quantity of the 10 top commodities </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="right">
<img class="average" src="average.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
<figcaption> Fig2. Averages per metric ton </figcaption>
</figure>
```

I want to put these figures so that they are side by side. I tried to make first one float:left and second one float:right, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply `float: left` to both figures.

Also, it might be useful this approach:

```html
<style>
.line{  /* Describes only positioning behaviour */
    display: block; /* Not important, but helpful in this case */
    clear: both;    /* Not important, but helpful in this case */
}

.line__figure{ /* Describes only positioning behaviour */
    float:left;
}

.figure{ /* Describes only view representation. */
    display: block; /* Not important, but helpful in this case */
}

.figure__image{
    background: lightgray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
<article>
    <section class='line'>
        <figure class="line__figure figure">
            <img class="figure__image top" src="top10.jpg" />
            <figcaption>Fig1. Production value and quantity
            of the 10 top commodities</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="line__figure figure">
            <img class="figure__image average" src="average.jpg" />
            <figcaption>Fig2. Averages per metric ton</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
    <section class='line'>
    Some text
    </section>
</article>
```

Ideas:

- divide a flow-behaviour and visual representation logic.
- use [Block, Element, Modifier](https://en.bem.info/) approach.

Answer (score 4):

As `figure` is a block level element, add this CSS rule and make it inline and it will be side by side if there is enough space.

```
.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="left">
  <img class="top" src="top10.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
  <figcaption> Fig1. Production value and quantity of the 10 top commodities </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure class="right">
  <img class="average" src="average.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
  <figcaption> Fig2. Averages per metric ton </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of float try using align, that might work. You can also use a table and put your images in one row but in two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Parent element need to have enough width to float left and right

```html
<div style="width:1000px">
    <figure class="left" style="float:left">
    <img class="top" src="top10.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
    <figcaption> Fig1. Production value and quantity of the 10 top commodities </figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure class="right" style="float:right">
    <img class="average" src="average.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
    <figcaption> Fig2. Averages per metric ton </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```